# SqlParameter with name is not contained in the parameter collection

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I keep getting this error

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sqlcon.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
        sqlcon.Open();

    SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("MG_Reviews_Task",sqlcon);
    sqlcmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@result ", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    int result = int.Parse(sqlcmd.Parameters["@result"].Value.ToString());

    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@re ", Txtname.Text.Trim());
    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@task", TextBox2.Text.Trim());
    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@proj",TextBox3.Text.Trim());
    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@company",TextBox4.Text.Trim());
    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@manager",TextBox5.Text.Trim());
    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@res",TextBox6.Text.Trim());
    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@deadline ",TextBox7.Text.Trim());

    sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    sqlcon.Close();

    if (result== 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("unathorized use");
    }
    else
        Console.WriteLine("success");
```

I have a stored procedure that has a an output variable result and this variable is updated according to a if condition.

I want to make a condition in asp.net to check when result = 1 and print a statement, the problem is that I keep getting the above error

Comment: Can you post your stored procedure too?

Comment: You are using the `@result` parameter before calling the proc. Also shouldn't be using `AddWithValue` at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move this line int result = int.Parse(sqlcmd.Parameters["@result"].Value.ToString()); to after sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();